# Refresh page with new data after Update in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a MVC5 page that is shows Customer's information in Text box then you can update some of the data and push Update button. it is going to update info but it is not showing the new value after pushing the update button, you have to leave a page and comeback to see a new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UpdateCustomer` and (presumably) `UpdatePassword` should not return a View but instead should return a `RedirectResponse` back to the `[HttpGet]` version of the  `Edit` action. This is known as a Post-Redirect-Get pattern and is the preferred way of redisplaying the same page the user just edited. By returning the view with the same model that was posted you're just showing the user what they originally typed in. You're also leaving yourself open to multi-postback situations if the user tries refreshing their browser.

You also seem to be fighting the framework. If you've got two buttons on the page that perform two different actions you should have two forms that each POST to a different controller action.